# Separate permissions or facebook IDs on different platforms?

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook

I'm implementing posting to facebook from our mobile applications (ios & android). The iPhone and android app already send us the picture and message, so if possible I would like to post the picture and message via php.

However I am wondering if this is possible, or if the request to post to facebook has to come from the mobile device from which they logged in to facebook from.

It seems as though I am getting back different facebook IDs when getting the user information from ios and from my website.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: If you are using different App ids on the different platforms you will get different user ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a session when you successfully log in in your mobile device. Just send the session from the mobile device to your server then call facebook php sdk for posting using this session. And you do not need separate permission for the same facebook app. But for different facebook you need separate permission regardless of you underlying platform.

Comment: When you say "send the session from the mobile device" what exactly do I need to send in order to load the session from my server. I'm looking at the session in xCode and it has an accessToken string. Would I pass that over and load the session from the accessToken?

Comment: yes accessToken this access token you required to send to server.